# Index of regularity equals regularity of homogeneous ideal?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ideals, krull-dimension, hilbert-polynomial

Notation:

- Let $HF_{M}(d)$ and $HP_M(d)$ denote the Hilbert-function resp. the
  Hilbert-polynomial.
  $\newcommand{\reg}{\operatorname{reg}}\newcommand{\depth}{\operatorname{depth}}$
- Let $i_{\reg}(I)$ denote the *index of
  regularity* of $I$, i.e. the smallest integer s.t. $HF_{R/I}(d) =
     HP_{R/I}(d)$ for all $d \geq i_{\reg}(I)$.
- Let $\reg(I)$ denote the Castelnuovo-Mumford regularity of $I$.

**I'm trying** to prove the following statement:

> If $I\subset R = k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is a homogeneous ideal and $I_d = R_d$ for $d \gg 0$, then $i_{\reg}(I) = \reg(I)$.

Apparently this should follow directly from the following Corollary from [Eisenbud's  Book](https://www.msri.org/people/staff/de/ready.pdf):

> Corollary 4.15: Let $M$ be a finitely generated graded Cohen-Macaulay $R$-module. If $s$ is the smallest number such that $HF_M(d) = HP_{M}(d)$ for all $d \geq s$,
> then $s = 1 − \depth(M) + \reg(M)$.

**What I did** was this:

From $I_d = R_d$ follows that $HF_{R/I}(d) = 0$ for $d \gg 0$, and therefore the Hilbert-polynomial is zero. As far as I've understood, this implies that $R/I$ has krull-dimension zero. 
This then implies that $\depth(R/I) = {\rm kdim}(R/I) = 0$, i.e $R/I$ is Cohen-Macaulay.
Now Corollary 4.15 implies that $i_{\reg}(I) = 1-0+\reg(R/I) \neq \reg(I)$.

What have I missed?

I think $\reg(R/I) = \reg(I) + 1$, so the result would be $2$ apart from what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it is $-1$ instead of $+1$ in the last equation.

Comment: Thank you. I'm sure you're right, but I based my statement on the following:
Let $I$ be the ideal with minimal resolution of the form:
$ \ldots \rightarrow \oplus R(-j)^{b_{i,j}} \rightarrow I \rightarrow 0$.
Then the minimal resolution of $R/I$ follows from that of I:
$ \ldots \rightarrow \oplus R(-j)^{b_{i,j}} \rightarrow R \rightarrow R/I \rightarrow 0$.

From this it should follow that $reg(R/I) = reg(I) + 1$ right?
(I don't find the reference anymore, but there it was proven  this way)

Comment: @horus189 Perhaps https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.5969.pdf (Remark 2.2)?

Comment: @horus189 I guess the statement that you were trying to prove is from some paper. Can you please tell me the source? I would like to have a look.

Comment: Sure, it's  <https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.06319.pdf>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$0\to F_k\to F_{k-1}\to\cdots\to F_0\to I\to 0$$
be the minimal free resolution of $I$, with $F_i=\oplus_jR(-a_{i,j})$. Then
$$0\to F_k\to F_{k-1}\to\cdots\to F_0\to S\to S/I\to 0$$
is the minimal free resolution of $S/I$.

By definition, ${\rm reg}(I)=\max_{i,j}a_{i,j}-i$. In the minimal free resolution of $S/I$, the free module $F_i$ is in the $(i+1)$-th position and the $0$-th term $S$ doesn't affect the regularity. Thus
$${\rm reg}(R/I)=\max_{i,j}a_{i,j}-(i+1)=\max_{i,j}a_{i,j}-i-1={\rm reg}(I)-1.$$